# Anyone know this "LocationAwareException"?

Tags: android, exception, build

Anyone know WTF is this? This exception comes out when I rebuild project in Android Studio, I have no idea what is this, please help.

Comment: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, all problem solved after reinstalling my OS.